# How to implement chart js using viewbag in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I am using the following code in my MVC application on visual studio to generate a pie chart using the chartjs JavaScript framework. The text does get displayed in the console on the browser. But the chart is not visible.

The following error I get is undefined based on this property [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ProductSalesCountName)]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Pie Charts</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var PieChartData =
        {
            labels: [@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ProductSalesCountName)],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'ProductWise Sales Count',
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#f990a7",
                    "#aad2ed",
                    "#9966FF",
                    "#99e5e5",
                    "#f7bd83",
                ],
                borderWidth: 2,
                data: [@ViewBag.ProductSalesCount]
            }]
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            var ctx1 = document.getElementById("Piecanvas").getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1,
                {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: PieChartData,
                    options:
                        {
                            title:
                            {
                                display: true,
                                text: "ProductWise Sales Count"
                            },
                            responsive: true,
                            maintainAspectRatio: true
                        }
                });
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <canvas id="Piecanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
    Disclaimer:- This data is for demo it is
    not real data it wont relate to any company
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your serialization does not produce a valid javascript array.
First remove the square brackets from `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ProductSalesCountName)`
And in the `controller` use `Newtonsoft.Json` for the serialization.

```
ViewBag.ProductSalesCountName= 
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```